# How can reset a React child component back to original state after it updates state in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, parent-child, rerender

I am new-ish to React and trying mimic a more complicated version of the following scenario:

1. I have a parent component that has a state variable.
2. I have a child component that I pass a function to that updates the state variable in the parent.
3. In my parent function, I want to be able to reset the state variable that the child might have changed.
4. I want the child function to reflect the reset that is initiated by the parent.

In my real example that I am mimicking here, in step 2, lots of things change in response to the updating of the state value, not just a direct update of the value. I want to provide a "reset" in my parent, that in turn should be reflected in this one child component that has a range slider.

Here is my simple example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const App = () => {
  const [rangeValue, setRangeValue] = useState(0)

  const reset = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setRangeValue(0)//reset state to 0 in App
    //how can I get the initial Position in Range component back to 0?
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>The range value is: {rangeValue}</p>
      <Range setRangeValue = {setRangeValue}/>
      <p><a href="/#" onClick={reset}>reset</a></p>
    </div>
  )
}

const Range = ({setRangeValue: setRangeValue}) =>
{
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setRangeValue(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <input 
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      step="1"
      defaultValue={0}
      onChange={(event) => {handleChange(event)}} />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here is a code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/FergusDevelopmentLLC/range-test

What is the proper way to accomplish such an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to make your Range component [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by passing the value to it from the parent and getting rid of the default

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const App = () => {
  const [rangeValue, setRangeValue] = useState(0)

  const reset = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setRangeValue(0)//reset state to 0 in App
    //how can I get the initial Position in Range component back to 0?
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>The range value is: {rangeValue}</p>
      {/* pass the value here */}
      <Range rangeValue={rangeValue} setRangeValue = {setRangeValue}/> 
      <p><a href="/#" onClick={reset}>reset</a></p>
    </div>
  )
}

const Range = ({rangeValue, setRangeValue: setRangeValue}) =>
{
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setRangeValue(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <input 
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      step="1"
      value={rangeValue} // <-- here get the value from parent, when reset it will come down from parent again without whatever value it was reset to
      onChange={(event) => {handleChange(event)}} />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you, your post gave me the idea of how to get past this. In my more complicated version, the slider is a Range: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider

But the solution was the same, to use a controlled version.